# Angular 2 add style based on pipe result

Tags: angular

I am not sure, if this is possible.

```
<span class="nav-label second-level-text" style="margin-left: 10px;">
{{partner.name}}
    <span class="badge"
      *ngIf="unreadConversations.length > 0 | unreadConversationForPartner : [unreadConversations,partner.id]">
    {{unreadConversations.length | unreadConversationForPartner : [unreadConversations,partner.id]}}
    </span>
</span>
```

I have the span over here. And I am applying filter to the `*ngIf` and also displaying the value of returned filter(which is the count)

I will like to display a style if the count returned from the pipe is greater than 0, and if not don't display the style. However I am able to achieve this by `*ngIf and Filter` but if the value of the `Filter` is changed, then the `*ngIf` doesnot change.

For instance. I have 2 items in the array.

Item 1: The length is 1 and it displays the span and does its job...

Item 2: At start the length is 0 and it does not display ( which is right behaviour) but the filter value changes, but then the `*ngIf` is not called again.

`unreadConversationForPartner pipe`

```
transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
        var count = 0;
        var partnerId = args[0][1];
        var conversations = args[0][0];
        conversations.forEach(element => {
            if(element.partnerId == partnerId) count++
        });
        return count;
    }
```

Let me know if the information provided is not enough or clear.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `as` that was introduced a while ago

```
*ngIf="unreadConversations.length > 0 | unreadConversationForPartner : [unreadConversations,partner.id] as result"
```

and then use it in other directives or bindings

```
[ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: result >= 5 ? 'red' : 'blue'}"
```

See also https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-conditional-result-in-a-variable

Comment: Thanks. You forgot to add `}` in `[ngStyle]` `[ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: result >= 5 ? 'red' : 'blue'}`

Comment: Thanks for the hint :) - fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting the same behaviour. After the `ngif` has ran once, it will not run it again after `unreadConversations` has changed.

Comment: Try changing `[unreadConversations,partner.id]` to `unreadConversations: partner.id` and `transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {` to `transform(value: any, unreadConversations:any, partnerId:any): any {`.

Comment: nope. It doesn't. I have attached the image in question. hope that helps.

Comment: Can you reproduce in Plunker?

Comment: I think so. Let me try.

Comment: btw, the `unreadConversations` is a observable. May be that can help.

Comment: Then you need to use the `| async` pipe` like `*ngIf="(unreadConversations | async)?.length > 0 | unreadConversationForPartner : (unreadConversations | async):partner.id` as result"`. I'm not sure using the pipe in the pipe parameter list is actually supported. Alternatively you can subscribe to the observable in code, assign the result to a field and bind to that field instead.

Comment: Your alternative seems promising. but The `<span>` is in a for loop. And I am trying to get the count based on PartnerId. How Can I achieve that?

Comment: What does that mean "And I am trying to get the count based on PartnerId."? `as result` holds the value you return from `transform`.

Comment: I had to remove the condition from the `*ngIf`