# How to store and use angular pipe result to add ngClass in html file

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

What I am doing:

**html file**

```
 <div *ngFor='let result of results'>
    <div [ngClass]='{"myclass": someArray | inArray:result.id}'>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**ts file:**

```
someArray = [1, 2, 3]

results = [
{id:1, name:'abc'},
{id:2, name:'xyz'},
{id:4, name:'pqr'}]
```

**Result**: I never get assigned class.

How can I store result of pipe in html file using "as" to use it in ngClass?

**inArray (pipe)**: Pipe returns true or false based on if value exists in array.

Referred [Angular 2 add style based on pipe result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410723/angular-2-add-style-based-on-pipe-result):

**Update 1:**

**inArray (pipe)**: Pipe returns -1 or index value based on if value exists in array.

**UPDATE 2:**
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nevhxm-so-at45c1)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I think you're looking for [Custom pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes)

Comment: @rmjoia I have already created custom pipe which returns value. I want to use that custom pipe to add class to element.

Comment: I don't understand what " to add class to element." means

Comment: you mean, the selected value is assigned to a property on the component?

Comment: @rmjoia I meant ngClass in html. Please check my code. I am trying to assign ngClass to div using custom pipe result but it does not work.

Comment: Ah.. you want to assign a css class based on a conditional, the value that is returned from the pipe, is that it?

Comment: i think you need a pipe that will filter your array and exclude unwanted classes

Comment: Can you please create a simple functional example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)? I will try to help

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud apparently the OP is saying that he gets none.. not all

Comment: How about the old/classic way : [class.myclass]="someArray[result.id]" ?

Comment: @vega I am trying to assign class if key exist in an array. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, this is what you're looking for!

Sorry I had to take care of something and only got back now..

Check the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nevhxm-so)

Only applies the class if the value is present.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'inArray' })
export class inArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, exponent: any): boolean {
    let result = value.indexOf(exponent);
    return result > -1;
  }
}
```

The rest is your code.. but It's all working together in the Stackblitz example above.

Comment: Thanks a lot rmjoia for taking time out to answer this with usage of pipe. Could you check out fork where I have altered pipe and it stopped working. Thanks.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nevhxm-so-at45c1

Comment: @Harsimer has to return a boolean or a truthy value.. something is not working, I'll have to debug... please standby

Comment: I found the issue. My pipe is checking value incorrectly. item === value instead of item.value === value

Comment: same, and saved your fork :) glad I could help :) don't forget to mark the answer (you consider the best) as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this - bind the class name to the property binding and use your pipe

`[class.myclass]='someArray | inArray:result.id'`

Your pipe will return true or false based on the condition the class will be added to the specific html

Hope this helps - happy coding :)

Comment: Rahul thanks for the answer. I have made a small update in Post. My pipe returns -1 or index value of key in array instead of true or false.

Answer (score 0):

The `pipes` should be used to transform values.

Try using a simple function to check this:

```
inArray(value, theArray) {
   return theArray.includes(value);
}
```

and the template:

```
 <div *ngFor='let result of results'>
    <div [ngClass]='{"myclass": inArray(result, results)}'>
    </div>
 </div>
```

or even **without the function**:

```
 <div *ngFor='let result of results'>
    <div [ngClass]='{"myclass": results.includes(result)'>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Andrew Radulescu, but isn't it bad practice to use function directly in html to assign a class as it will cause issue with change detection?

Comment: No, it is not. This will re-render and re-call the function only when the results array is changed. It's a common usage :). More, the pipe will do exactly the same `for each element will run a function to transform the given values`.

Comment: Andrew Radulescu Thanks for clarifying, but sometimes I have expirienced "expression checked after value changed" error while using functions directly in html template. So I was trying to avoid usage of functions directly in html.

Comment: This would happen if you update the `results` array in the function that checks that array. Won't happen in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used a directive with inputs, when the directive inputs change, the required style can be calculated and applied on the directive input. Taken from answers here: [Angular2 Styles in a Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915433/angular2-styles-in-a-directive)

Answer (score -1):

You can use function for this :
[ngClass]="isValueInArray()" 
  and return value true/false in that function

Comment: Shifali singla I am trying to avoid calling function in template file.